# Boolean Check in a Pandas DataFrame based on Criteria at different Index values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to calculate the number of instances two criteria are fulfilled in a Pandas DataFrame at a different index value. A snipped of the DataFrame is:

```
                GDP  USRECQ
DATE                        
1947-01-01       NaN       0
1947-04-01       NaN       0
1947-07-01       NaN       0
1947-10-01       NaN       0
1948-01-01  0.095023       0
1948-04-01  0.107998       0
1948-07-01  0.117553       0
1948-10-01  0.078371       0
1949-01-01  0.034560       1
1949-04-01 -0.004397       1
```

I would like to count the number of observation for which `USRECQ[DATE+1]==1 and GDP[DATE]>a if GDP[DATE]!='NAN'`.

By referring to `DATE+1` and `DATE` I mean that the value of `USRECQ` should be check at the subsequent date for which the value of `GDP` is examined. Unfortunately, I do not know how to address the deal with the different time indices in my selection. Can someone kindly advise me on how to count the number of instances properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may of achieving this is to create a new column to show what the next value of 'USRECQ' is:

```
>>> df['USRECQ NEXT'] = df['USRECQ'].shift(-1)
>>> df
         DATE       GDP  USRECQ  USRECQ NEXT
0  1947-01-01       NaN       0            0
1  1947-04-01       NaN       0            0
2  1947-07-01       NaN       0            0
3  1947-10-01       NaN       0            0
4  1948-01-01  0.095023       0            0
5  1948-04-01  0.107998       0            0
6  1948-07-01  0.117553       0            0
7  1948-10-01  0.078371       0            1
8  1949-01-01  0.034560       1            1
9  1949-04-01 -0.004397       1          NaN
```

Then you could filter your DataFrame according to your requirements as follows:

```
>>> a = 0.01
>>> df[(df['USRECQ NEXT'] == 1) & (df['GDP'] > a) & (pd.notnull(df['GDP']))]

         DATE       GDP  USRECQ  USRECQ NEXT
7  1948-10-01  0.078371       0            1
8  1949-01-01  0.034560       1            1
```

To count the number of rows in a DataFrame, you can just use the built-in function `len`.

Comment: it's probably better to replace the `~pd.isnull` wit `pd.notnull`for readability

Comment: @EdChum - thanks; I agree `pd.notnull` is more readable and have edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `DataFrame.shift` method is the key to what you seek in terms of looking at the next index.

And Numpy's logical expressions can come in really handy for these sorts of things.

So if df is your dataframe then I think what you're looking for is something like

```
count = df[np.logical_and(df.shift(-1)['USRECQ'] == 1,df.GDP > -0.1)]
```

The example I used to test this is on [github](https://github.com/yatinla/stackoverflow/tree/master/20140928).